# I want to have a favicon that represents the web page

Tags: eclipse

When I run the code in Eclipse, I want to have a favicon that represents the web page. However, as shown in the figure, the code does not display the favicon. I want to know how to fix it.

figure :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQN2v.jpg

Here's the code I run to make the favicon appear:

```
<link rel="icon" href="css/favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/favicon.ico?v=2" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Where did you place that icon?

Comment: Click the link : https://imgur.com/a/PrqKc6Y , then you can find the icon in css folder